# Selection sort not grabbing last element in array

Tags: c++, selection-sort

```
void ProcessSort(int studentIDs[], string studentNames[], int num)
{

   for (int i = 0; i < num - 1; i++)
   {
      int mindex = 0; 
      //DO6: finish the inner loop
      //     Hint: it should start from i+1 and go until num-1
      //     if studentNames[j] is greater than studentNames[mindex]
      //     then store j in mindex
      for (int j = i+1; j < num - 1; j++) {
         if (studentNames[mindex] < studentNames[j]) {
            mindex = j;
         }
      }



      //DO7: Swap student names

      SwapNames(studentNames[mindex], studentNames[i]);

      //DO8: Swap student IDs'
      SwapIDs(studentIDs[mindex], studentIDs[i]);


   }
   cout << "Class List sorted by name." << endl;
}
```

Selection sort seems not to grab last element in array. There are two parallel arrays, one with names and one with ids, but it seems to be that the last name in the student names array isnt registered with the sort. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: "Hint: it should ... go until num-1" but it does not. With `for (int j = i+1; j < num - 1; j++)` what do you think the highest used `j` will be?

Comment: I am severly confused. I tried num - 2, num -3 and even just num. I don't know what you mean the highest used j would be.

Comment: I do not know how to phrase that differently. Look at the loop. It will increase j consecutively. What will be the last value of `j` which will be processed in the loop body? Will it be `num-1` as in the hint provided by teacher? If changing the loop so that the last will is indeed num-1 does not help, then look for more mistakes. If you provide an [mre] you might find help with that. Assumig that `//DON` means something for you to "DO", then the mistakes might easily be inside the code you do not show. Since the answer by Vlad did not satisfy you, it seems that there are more issues to find.

Answer (score 0):

The body of the outer loop should look at least like

```
  int mindex = i; 
  //DO6: finish the inner loop
  //     Hint: it should start from i+1 and go until num-1
  //     if studentNames[j] is greater than studentNames[mindex]
  //     then store j in mindex
  for (int j = i+1; j < num; j++) {
     if (studentNames[mindex] < studentNames[j]) {
        mindex = j;
     }
  }
```

This condition

```
     if (studentNames[mindex] < studentNames[j]) {
```

provides sorting in the descending order.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

void ProcessSort( int studentIDs[], std::string studentNames[], size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t  i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        size_t mindex = i; 
        //DO6: finish the inner loop
        //     Hint: it should start from i+1 and go until num-1
        //     if studentNames[j] is greater than studentNames[mindex]
        //     then store j in mindex
        for ( size_t j = i + 1; j < n; j++ ) 
        {
            if ( studentNames[mindex] < studentNames[j] ) mindex = j;
        }

        //DO7: Swap student names
        if ( i != mindex )
        {
            std::swap( studentNames[mindex], studentNames[i] );
            //DO8: Swap student IDs'
            std::swap( studentIDs[mindex], studentIDs[i] );
        }
    }
}

int main() 
{
    int studentIDs[] = { 495, 520, 550, 666 };
    std::string studentNames[] = { "Kyle", "Liam", "Bill", "Michael" };
    const size_t N = sizeof( studentIDs ) / sizeof( *studentIDs );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << "( " << studentNames[i] << ", " << studentIDs[i] << " ) ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    ProcessSort( studentIDs, studentNames, N );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << "( " << studentNames[i] << ", " << studentIDs[i] << " ) ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
( Kyle, 495 ) ( Liam, 520 ) ( Bill, 550 ) ( Michael, 666 ) 
( Michael, 666 ) ( Liam, 520 ) ( Kyle, 495 ) ( Bill, 550 )
```

Comment: 520           Liam
    495           Kyle
    550           Bill
    666        Michael  michael is at the end when he should be afer liam

Comment: @user3570933 it seems you forgot to change the condition in the inner loop.